# showDatePciker throwing an error in Flutter Project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, datepicker

I am trying to load Date from showDatePicker. But when i run the code I get the following error. Unable to understand where am I going wrong. Please help me
This is the Error I am getting. Where should i use the future unable to understand. Can somebody tell me how can this error be resolved. Any help would be appreciated

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type '(() => void)?'

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditTask extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const EditTask({
    Key? key,
    //this.taskModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditTaskState createState() => _EditTaskState();
}

class _EditTaskState extends State<EditTask> {
  
  late DateTime selectedDate;
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    selectedDate = DateTime.now();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Task'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(
                    "${selectedDate.day}/${selectedDate.month}/${selectedDate.year}"),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: _selectDate(context), icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? selected = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2010),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
    );
    if (selected != null && selected != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = selected;
      });
  }

  
}
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: The error is on `IconButton` `onPressed` parameter where you call your `_selectDate` method instead of passing it like `IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => _selectDate(context), icon: Icon(Icons.edit)),`

Comment: Thnx i just missed it

Answer (score 0):

Change the `onPressed` function in `IconButton`

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
        _selectDate(context);
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
),
```